# c++ win 32application: Employee Class array issue

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Im having a issue with my employee class. The program itself has a sample employee and allows the user to input more employees to the program. The issue I am having is that I can add in 1 new employee and print the list of both the sample employee and the newly added employee, however when i try to add in a second employee and print, the second one with over write the first added employee.

Im not sure if the issue is with the array im using (which has 4 elements, number, first name, last name and department) or if its with the function thats being called, below the code ive done up.

header file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class employee
{

public :
    employee();
    employee(int, char*, char*, char*); // employee works number, name, department
    void Set( int, char*, char*, char*); // set the number, name and dept
    void Print();
    void printmenu();
    ~employee(); //destructor

private: 
    int e_num; // employee number
    char e_fname[30];
    char e_lname [30];
    char e_dept[30];

};
```

CPP File:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "employee.h"
using namespace std;


employee::employee() 
{

}

employee::employee(int num, char* fname, char* lname, char* dept)
{
    Set(num, fname, lname, dept);
}

void employee::Set( int num, char* fname, char* lname, char* dept)
{
    if (num < 0 )
    {
    return ; // add in code here to give error message if works is less than 0
    }
    e_num = num;
    strcpy (e_fname, fname);
    strcpy (e_lname, lname);
    strcpy (e_dept, dept);

}

void employee::Print()
{
        cout << e_num <<" \t " << e_fname <<" "<< e_lname <<" \t " << e_dept << " \n";
}

void employee::printmenu()
{
    cout << "EMPLOYEE MENU\n"
         << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"
         << "1. Add New Employee\n"
         << "2. Edit Employee\n"
         << "3. Delete Employee\n"
         << "4. Print Employee List\n"
         << "5. Exit\n";
}

employee::~employee()
{

}
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "employee.h"
using namespace std;

void main (void)
{
    char input;
    bool done = false;  

    employee emp1(1, "Joe", "Bloggs", "Customer Service");// sample employee
    int empcount = 1;
    employee empnew[20];

    int num, j=0, k=0; // num is employee number
    char* fname = new char [20]; // employee first name
    char* lname = new char [20];  // employee last name
    char* dept  = new char [30]; // employee department


    while(!done)
    {       
    employee pmenu;
    pmenu.printmenu();

    cout <<"Please make your selection:";
    cin >> input;

    switch (input)
    {
    case '1': // add new employee

        cout<<"\nEnter Employee Number:";   
        cin >> num;
        cout<<"\nEnter first name:";
        cin >> fname;
        cout<<"\nEnter Last name:";
        cin >> lname;
        cout << "\nEnter Department:";
        cin >> dept;
        cout << "\n";

        empnew[j].Set(num, fname, lname, dept);
        empcount++;

        cout << "New employee added:"<< fname <<" "<<lname << "\n";
        cout<< "New Number of Employees:" << empcount<< "\n\n";
        break; 

    case '2': //Edit Employee
    // enter stuff here
        break;

    case '3': //Delete Employee
    // enter stuff here
        break;
    case '4': // print employee list

        cout <<"Total number of Employees:"<<empcount<<endl;
        cout <<"Number \t Employee Name \t Department \n" ;

        if (empcount == 1)
        {
            emp1.Print(); 
        }
        else 
        {
            emp1.Print(); 
            empnew[j].Print();//print input
        }
        cout <<"\n";
        break;
    case '5':
        cout << "Program closing\n";
        done = true;
        break;

    }

    }
    getchar();
    return ;
}
```

(sorry for posting all the code, didnt want to leave something important out)

Ive tried several different ways to get the 2nd (and subsequent employee) to print but which ever way i try to change the array or the function i get errors and the code wont compile.

I thought when added the new employee to use

```
empnew[j]= new employee (num ,fname,lname,dept);
```

but that gives me "Error: no operator "=" matches these operands"

along with many other variations of that which dont work either.

As you might guess ive just started with c++ so any help would be greatly appricated.

Comment: Why are you using `char` arrays instead of `std::string`?

Comment: i tried using string but when it came to copying it i was having issues eg. my compiler didnt like strcpy when i was using the string. which is why i stuck with char.

Comment: That's because you don't have to use `strcpy` when using the C++ string class, just assign one to the other like a normal value.

Comment: so in the cpp file (when its a string) in employee::Set have it as string e_fname = fname; ?

Comment: Yes. `std::string foo = "foo"; std::string bar = foo; std::cout << bar;` will print `"foo"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set employee data into `empnew[j]` array item, yet `j` variable never changes. Judging from this snippet:

```
empnew[j].Set(num, fname, lname, dept);
empcount++;
```

probably you should change into to

```
empnew[empcount++].Set(num, fname, lname, dept);
```

Comment: that wont print the names just a load of rubbish/ mess :(

Comment: @CM99 This is the correct answer. The reason you get rubbish with your printing code is that you also have bugs in that part of the code. Make this fix, and then think about what's wrong with your printing code. Basically you seem to be confused with how to use arrays and loops and also how to count how many items you have in an array.

Comment: @CM99, to print all employees you have to use a loop (e.g. `for`). Also note, that `int empcount = 1;` and array's indexes are start from zero, so empnew[0] won't been set.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` operator returns a *pointer* and you have an array of values.

Either you have to create an array of pointers, or (what I recommend) implement a copy-constructor and use copying:

```
empnew[j] = employee (num ,fname, lname, dept);
```